# OpenGL & GLM Translation matrix stretched

Tags: c++, opengl, matrix, glm-math

I've been following a tutorial(for java which i'm adapting to c++) to write a game using OpenGL but I'm having an issue at the translation matrix part. My sprite gets stretched when I change it's position:

positon {-1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f} 
[image]

position {0, 0, 0}
[image]

I don't have any experience with graphics programming so I really have no idea of what went wrong. Here is my code:

Shaders:

```
// VERTEX
#shader vertex
#version 330 core

layout(location = 0) in vec4 position;
layout(location = 1) in vec2 texCoord;

out vec2 v_TexCoord;


uniform mat4 u_TransformationMatrix;

void main() {
    gl_Position = position * u_TransformationMatrix;
    v_TexCoord = texCoord;
};

// FRAGMENT
#shader fragment
#version 330 core

layout(location = 0) out vec4 color;

in vec2 v_TexCoord;

uniform vec4 u_Color;
uniform  sampler2D u_Texture;

void main() {
    vec4 texColor = texture(u_Texture, v_TexCoord);
    color = texColor;
};
```

Calculation of the matrix:

```
static glm::mat4 createTransformationMatrix(glm::vec3 translation, glm::vec3 rotation, float scale) {
    glm::mat4 matrix(1.f);

    matrix = glm::translate(matrix, translation);
    matrix = glm::rotate(matrix, glm::radians(rotation.x), glm::vec3(1.f, 0.f, 0.f));
    matrix = glm::rotate(matrix, glm::radians(rotation.y), glm::vec3(0.f, 1.f, 0.f));
    matrix = glm::rotate(matrix, glm::radians(rotation.z), glm::vec3(0.f, 0.f, 1.f));
    matrix = glm::scale(matrix, glm::vec3(scale));


    return matrix;
}
```

Rendering code:

```
void Render(const Renderer &renderer, Shader *shader) {
    shader->SetUniformMatrix4f("u_TransformationMatrix", Math::createTransformationMatrix(position, rotation, scale));
    model.Render(renderer, *shader);
}
```

Texture loading code:

```
Texture::Texture(const std::string & path, bool useTiling) : m_RendererId(0), m_FilePath(path), m_LocalBuffer(nullptr), m_Width(0), m_Height(0), m_BPP(0)
{
    stbi_set_flip_vertically_on_load(false);
    m_LocalBuffer = stbi_load(path.c_str(), &m_Width, &m_Height, &m_BPP, 4/*RGBA*/);
    glGenTextures(1, &m_RendererId);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_RendererId);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, useTiling ? GL_REPEAT : GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, useTiling ? GL_REPEAT : GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8, m_Width, m_Height, 0/*b*/, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, m_LocalBuffer);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

    if (m_LocalBuffer)
        stbi_image_free(m_LocalBuffer);
}
```

Comment: Usually, the multiplication order in shader is Matrix * Vector and not Vector * Matrix, unless you transposed your matrices.

Comment: That solved it, thank you. I thought the order didn't matter (like in regular multiplications).

Comment: You should look into matrix math. Order matters in almost all matrix operations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The multiplication order in the shader is wrong. Replace

```
gl_Position = position * u_TransformationMatrix;
```

with

```
gl_Position = u_TransformationMatrix * position;
```

[Matrix multiplications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication) are not [commutative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property).